# NSCFSet objectAtIndex unrecognized selector, iterating works

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector

I was wondering how it can be that iterating through an NSMutableArray works, but when I call objectAtIndex it fails with "*** -[NSCFSet objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x..."

Here is some sample code, the program is too big to share in whole so I hope it's enough. The code is executed in the latest iPhone Simulator from XCode.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 RDLogString(@"Creating cell @ row no. %d", indexPath.row);
 CPPlayerAppDelegate * appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 RDLogString(@"Conversations: %p. Item count: %d", appDelegate.distribution.conversations, appDelegate.distribution.conversations.count);  
 //This works  
 for(CPConversation * x in appDelegate.distribution.conversations){
  RDLogString(@"Pointer: %p with name %@", x, x.name);
 }  
 //This fails with aforementioned error  
 CPConversation * conversationAtCurrentIndex = [appDelegate.distribution.conversations objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
```

Sorry for the bad formatting, still figuring it out. :)

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objectAtIndex:` is part of `NSArray`, not `NSSet`.  This means your `appDelegate.distribution.conversations` is returning an `NSSet` and  you need an `NSArray`.

Comment: Thanks to both! I had defined it as an NSMutableArray, but further I initialized it with [[NSMutableSet alloc] init]; xD

Sometimes I miss C(++)'s static typing. It must've been a warning but I got so many... I need to pay more attention to those. Anyhow, thanks a lot.

Comment: Aye, no edit. It's not even a warning. Just got to be careful I guess. Any suggestions to spot such errors?

Comment: The problem is that NSMutableArray's designated initializer -- along with NSSet and NSDictionary -- are declared as returning (id) and, thus, any method on any class is considered valid.  The reason they are declared that way is because Objective-C doesn't support covariant declarations.

Comment: As long as you avoid the (id) type, though, Objective-C does a fine job of supporting static type analysis (which I meant to add to the previous comment).

Answer (score 0):

That exception message is telling you that you're sending a message with a selector that the receiving class doesn't recognize or respond to. In this case, you're sending a `objectAtIndex:` message to an object of type `NSCFSet` (or just `NSSet`).

This means that whatever `appDelegate.distribution.conversations` is, you're expecting it to be an NSArray, but its actually an NSSet. How are you creating the object accessed there?